# How to insert a Parse Query first() call ahead of a series of Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() calls?

Tags: parse-platform, promise

How would I add this code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Obj1");
query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
query.first().then(function(obj) {
```

to the front of the chain in 'perform()'. Currently 'perform()' makes the two Parse.Cloud.httpRequest calls. I'd like it to do the Parse query first.

```
module.exports = {

    version: '1.0.0',

    initialize: function() {
        return this;
    },

    perform: function(options) {
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method:'POST',
            url:'http://...',
        }).then(function(httpResponse) {
            return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                method:'POST',
                url:'http://...',
            }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                return httpResponse;
            });
        }, function(httpResponse) {
            if (options && options.error) {
                options.error(httpResponse);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*as the first code in the function 'perform'*"? Do you want to chain it or what?

Comment: I've reworded the question to make it clear that if like to add to the front of the promise chain.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Have you tried something that didn't work? Do you want to do anything with the `obj` result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already demonstrates you understand thenable chaining, you can just apply it here:

```
// inside your function
var query = new Parse.Query("Obj1");
query.equalTo("user", Parse.User.current());
query.first().then(function(obj) {
     // use obj here
     return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method:'POST',
        url:'http://...',
     });
}).then(... // rest of your code
```

Comment: When added I get the error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined. Which is odd as Parse.com documentation uses query.first().then... as an example,

Comment: I removed query.equalTo() so that all rows of "Obj1" are returned (my Parse database has one row) but I get the same error message.